# How can I use the master theorem to get an upper bound on this recurrence?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

I Wrote an algorithm whose running time is described by the recurrence
$$T(n) = 2T(n/2) + \Theta(n\lg n),$$
and I want to determine whether $T(n) = o(n^2)$.

Now by the third case of the "Master Theorem" a recurrence of the form
$$T(n) = 2T(n/2) + f(n)$$
has solution $T(n) = \Theta(f(n))$, if $f(n) = \Omega(n^{1+\varepsilon})$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$.

I can't apply this directly to my recurrence since $n\lg n \neq \Omega(n^{1+\varepsilon})$, but if I can find a function $f(n)$ such that
$$n\lg n = \Omega(f(n))\qquad \text{ and } \qquad f(n) = \Omega(n^{1+\varepsilon}) \qquad\text{ and } \qquad f(n) = o(n^2),$$
then I can just use the master theorem on
$$T(n) = 2T(n/2) + f(n)$$
to get the bound. So is there such an $f(n)$?

Comment: To answer the question you actually asked, no, $n \log(n)$ does not dominate any $n^{1+\epsilon}$. That doesn't really solve your problem, however, so I don't think it is a good answer to the entire question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the Master Theorem's cases apply to your problem. In order to find the asymptotic running time of your recurrence, you need an extended version described in exercise 4.6-2 of CLRS book (extension of Case 2). Besides the Wikipedia to which Ian already referred, see also [here](https://donrwalsh.github.io/CLRS/solutions/04/e4.6-2) or [here](https://ita.skanev.com/04/06/02.html) for a proof of this case extension.

So you have $a=b=2, k=1$, and you get $T(n)=\Theta(n\lg^2n)=o(n^2)$

Comment: Pretty sure case 2 from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) applies here, with $c_{crit}=1$ and $k=1$. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Ian Yes, Wikipedia already has the extension case. CLRS has only $k=0$

Comment: @Ian Just to clarify: Yes = "you are correct" :)